# Plotting bisect method in matlab

Tags: matlab

So I had a problem in which I needed to find roots using the bisect method:

Function:

```
function [ c,k ] = bisect(f,a,b,tol)
k=0;
while b-a > tol
    c=(a+b)/2;
    if sign(f(c)) == sign(f(b))
        b=c;
    else
        a=c;
    end
    k=k+1;
end
```

Script:

```
f = @(x) (((1800).*log((160000)./(160000 - (x.*2600))) - (9.812).*x)./750) - 1;

a = 10;
b = 50;
tol = 1e-4;

[root, iter] = bisect(f,a,b,tol);
fprintf(' iterations = %i root = %15.10e ' ,iter, root);
```

This works perfectly, now I need to use an `embedded function` in `Matlab` to find the value of c for different values of q (in the above example q is a fixed number 2600) from 2000 to 3000 in increments of 10 and plot x vs q. In order to do this I have the following script:

```
function myFunction

h = 10; 
a = 10;
b = 50;
tol = 1e-4;

    function y = f(x)
        y = (((1800).*log((160000)./(160000 - (x.*q))) - (9.812).*x)./750) - 1;
    end
        for q = (2000:h:3000)
            k=0;
            while b-a > tol
                c=(a+b)/2;
                if sign(f(c)) == sign(f(b))
                    b=c;
                    cArray(q) = c;
                else
                    a=c;
                    cArray(q) = c;
                end
                k=k+1;
            end
        end
        plot(q,cArray)
end
```

This code has no errors but when I run it there is no graph. Can someone please help me with this issue? I don't even know if my code to find c vs q is correct.

Comment: One problem I spot is that you write `sign(f(c)))` when f is not defined anywhere. Go over Matlab documentation regarding functions...

Comment: Ok I made an edit separating my embedded function, this runs and provides a graph but it is not what I am expecting the y axis goes from 0-40 and the x goes from 2999 to 3000 with increments of .2 and there is no graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Major issues with your `myFunction` code:

1. The endpoints a,b should be reset within the `for` loop, so that the root search begins anew.
2. Using `q` as index in `cArray(q)` results in a too-large array filled with zeros for indices below 2000. You need an index variable to keep track of that array.  (I used `j` below)
3. `plot(q,cArray)` should be `plot(2000:h:3000,cArray)`, because `q` is not an array, it's a scalar.

Minor issues:

4. You never used `k`
5. You assign to `cArray(q)` within the while loop; this only needs to be done once the loop has ran.

#### Corrected function:

```
function myFunction
h = 10;
tol = 1e-4;
    function y = f(x)
        y = (((1800).*log((160000)./(160000 - (x.*q))) - (9.812).*x)./750) - 1;
    end

j = 0;
for q = 2000:h:3000
    a = 10;
    b = 50;
    while b-a > tol
        c=(a+b)/2;
        if sign(f(c)) == sign(f(b))
            b=c;
        else
            a=c;
        end
    end
    j=j+1;
    cArray(j)=c;
end
plot(2000:h:3000,cArray)
end
```

and its output:

[image: output]